# How can I achieve a material-ui v1.0.0 drop down in ReactJS?

Tags: material-ui

Currently, I am using some haddock method where I've tweaked the styles in order to emulate the material-ui drop down. A sample of the styles is shown below:

````
```elonSelect: {
        width: "70%",
        height: 50,
        fontSize: "120%",
        border: "none",
        borderBottom: "solid 1px",
        outline: 0,
        marginBottom: 50
    },
```
````

Is there a better way of doing this? Or should I just wait for updates from the material-ui team?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45676342/571724), which explains your current options for a select field while using material-ui v1.

Comment: Thanks [Ken Gregory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571724/ken-gregory)

Answer (score 0):

The [Select component](https://material-ui-next.com/api/select/) was released as of [version 1.0.0-beta.9](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.9).